# How to make a Property nullable in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

For a model file which looks like:

```
public class WebApiEntity
{
  public string id { get; set; }
  public Collection<CData> data { get; set; }
}


public class CData
{
  public string CType { get; set; }

  public string CId { get; set; }
}
```

When I generate an ODATA client using service reference, it looks something like:

```
<EntityType Name="WebApiEntity">
    <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="id" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="data" Type="Collection(NamespaceValue.CData)" Nullable="false" />
</EntityType>
```

It has nullable property set to FALSE. What do I have to do to set it to TRUE.
It seems Nullable<> can't be used here. Appreciate any help here.

Comment: What about using CData[] instead of collection type?

Comment: I think the `Nullable` has to do with whether it is a nullable type, ie `int?`, and since strings and collections are not value types, this doesn't pertain.

Comment: @Oscar Using an array is producing the ditto edm as collection

Comment: Question title and body disagree. Title asks how to make it non-nullable, which it appears it already is. Body seems to ask how to make it nullable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
var collectionProperty = builder.EntityType<WebApiEntity>().CollectionProperty<CData>(c=>c.data);
collectionProperty.IsOptional();
```

Comment: But will that make it nullable? From the looks of it, it should make it non nullable.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstand your question, and I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont see any method called EntityType inside builder. Typo?

Comment: No, it is not Typo, in new version of ODataConventionModelBuilder, the method Entity and AddEntity are replaced with EntityType and AddEntityType. So in your case just use builder.Entity<WebApiEntity>().

Comment: Tried it. Doesnt seem to help! :( Though the method IsOptional() appears to be for that only.

On a side note, if I replace the COllection<CData> by Collection<string>, it automatically becomes nullable.

Comment: But I tried it, it works on the new version. And the new Nuget package id is Microsoft.AspNet.OData.

Answer (score 0):

May could be useful for somebody.
One of solutions is to use CData as struct type (but you will get some restrictions). Structs are value types.

```
public class WebApiEntity
{
    public Collection<CData> data { get; set; }
    public Collection<(String CType, String CId)> data_tuple { get; set; } 
}

public struct CData
{
    public string CType { get; set; }
    public string CId { get; set; }
}
```

OData metadata:

```
<Property Name="data" Type="Collection(Diagnostics.Data.Diagnostics.CData)"/>
<Property Name="data_tuple" Type="Collection(System.ValueTuple_2OfString_String)"/>
```

[OData metadata pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSDaL.png)